# I want to update this dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

**tickets** is an empty dictionary in a file called Cities. I want to update the dictionary with new values after every time I run this program, but it ends up erasing the dictionary and adding only 1 key-value pair.

```
from Cities import tickets

a = {random.randint(1,999): random.randint(1,89898)}
tickets.update(a)
print(tickets)
```

Comment: When your program exits, it will lose its state unless you save that state to a file. Perhaps consider using the `json` module to save your dictionary to a file before your program exits, and load it up again when it starts up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the state between different executions of your script, you need to write to disk. Hence I suggest you use the built-in module [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html), as follows:

```
# cities.py
import shelve
tickets = shelve.open("data")
```

then use it from your script:

```
import random
from cities import tickets

with tickets:
    print(list(tickets.items()))
    a = {f"{random.randint(1, 999)}": random.randint(1, 89898)}
    tickets.update(a)
```

**Output** *(first run)*

```
[]
```

**Output** *(second run)*

```
[('900', 67984)]
```

The only **caveat** though is that the keys need to be strings.

**Note:** *(from the docs)* Do not rely on the shelf being closed automatically; always call `close()` explicitly when you don’t need it any more, or use `shelve.open()` as a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-context-manager).

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly because my keys are supposed to be strings anyway.

Comment: Apparently it suffices if the keys [quack like a string](https://tio.run/##hY5NDsIgEIX3c4rZFRrTBXZhTHqCHsG4IGUamiAQhmo8PaLBhSvf8v18efGZbfDHU0ylbLcYUka25O4EsDjNjLPYfJZnwCpDK5JfgiHB5NYD9rolbyXKe/LIOX1SObRqLQE8tmwbeQiRvOi4k6gZTUNfZjEqecUJR/Xr9BMqAEMOzX9OTPWu@G5lKS8) (not that I'd use that, I was just curious)